# Changing filterContext.Result in OnResultExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have a controller action that has an attribute applied in which if the ModelState has errors it sets them as the `JsonResult` in the `OnResultExecuting` method.

I set the value in `MyAction`. I change it in the attribute in `OnResultExecuting` but in the `OnResultExecuted` which is in the controller the result is the one from the controller not the one which was set in the attribute.

So my question is why does the value in `OnResultExecuted` remain unchanged and how do i make it stop doing that ?

```
public class MyController:Controller
{
    [ValidateDatedObject(SkipActionExecution = true, LeaveJustModelState = true)]
    public JsonResult MyAction(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { Success = false }}; // Setting the initial value
    }
    protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);//filterContext.Result here is the on from the controller instead of the one from the attribute
    }
}

public class ValidateDatedObject : ModelValidationFilter
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }//filterContext.Result here is the one from the attribute
}

public abstract class ModelValidationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private JsonResult getModelStateAsJsonResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { modelState = SerializeErrors(modelState) } };
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = getModelStateAsJsonResult(filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState); //Setting filterContext.Result here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because in the `OnResultExecuting` you are replacing the current result with a new instance. That will modify the result in the `ResultExecutingContext` but will leave the overall result unchanged.

You could however modify the result instead of replacing it

```
public abstract class ModelValidationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Modify the values in the current filterContext.Result instead of replacing it with a new instance
        var jsonResult = filterContext.Result as JsonResult;
        if(jsonResult == null) return;
        //possibly replace Data only under certain conditions
        jsonResult.Data = new { modelState = SerializeErrors(modelState) };
    }
}
```

The reason for this is the way ResultFilters are executed by MVC. You can check the implementation of [`ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerActionInvoker.cs). This is the code calling `OnResultExecuting` on each filter, executing the action and then calling `OnResultExecuted` in reverse order.

If you look carefully, you will notice that `ResultExecutedContext` is created with a reference to the original actionResult object, not with a reference to `ResultExecutingContext.Result`. (Unless you set `ResultExecutingContext.Cancel=true` which will stop processing additional filters and return whatever result it has at that moment, but that also means controller OnResultExecute won't be executed)

So there is an assumption in this code in that ResultFilters may modify the values of the properties in `ResultExecutingContext.Result` but not entirely replace it with a new instance.

Comment: Thank you that works, but the problem is that i did the same thing in `OnActionExecuting` without any problems. I know that's a different context but i find this behavior to be totally unexpected, maybe that's just me.

Comment: I was surprised too, that's why I ended up having a look at the implementation. It would be nice to know if this is by design or a bug/oversight

Comment: Thank you so much. It is ridiculous that it is implemented this way. It should have been implemented so that it takes the filterCotnext.result final object just like other filter attributes.

Comment: I just realized, my real issue is that what I want to do is better be OnActionExecuted of IActionFilter, not IResultFilter. There, changing the result changes the response.